# Map file specification?

Tags: debugging, gcc

Am creating a debugger tool.
I need the MAP file Structure specification for GCC compiler. 
In order to find how the memory is mapped for different variables of different Data types (class, inner class, static, static const, extern, template, typedef Variables Specification in MAP file). 
And also i want to know the way how the symbols are added to different variable to differentiate in the MAP file.
Tell me the way to proceed.

Comment: Removed the C# tag - no idea why that was there...

Comment: Do not use ALL CAPS in your question title.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that you need to understand the detailed MAP file format, -Wl and --print-map should be enough to get a readable textual map data from the compiler.

```
$ cat x.c | grep alpha
int alpha = one;
  int c = do_operation(alpha, b);
  printf( "%d op %d = %d\n", alpha, b, c);

$ g++ -Wl,--print-map ./x.c  | grep -P "(alpha|printf)"
                0x00000000080483f0                printf@@GLIBC_2.0
                0x000000000804a018                alpha
```

Above you can see that x.c contains declaration of variable "alpha" and also uses "printf". And as you can see that addresses are available via --print-map paramater

Hope this helps.

Comment: btw, in case you want to know how to read that text generated by --print-map here's the docs, remember to read up on ld documentation this is not light reading: http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.19/ld/Options.html#index-g_t_002d_002dprint_002dmap-62